# pay pal returnurl to return users pay pal account email address

Tags: php, email, paypal

I'm using PHP.

Is it possible when paypal returns to my site after taken the payment that it could also pass me the email address (paypal username) so that I may use this to send them an email?

I'm trying to keep my site as simple as possible and I don't want to ask the customer for a load of information up front.

My ideal flow would be:
Take Payment > Add record to database > email customer with username and password

The customer can then log in and fill the rest in at their own leisure.

Is it possible to get this variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows the things you can get back from PayPal after they process a payment.

[IPN and PDT Variables](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB04C0HS)

Here is on example I made in Codeigniter.

```
/* Receives a form data from paypal that is processed after payment goes through.
 * It will update the database entry with a transaction id. 
 */
 function epayment_notify(){
    $this->load->model('pament_notice_model');

    echo "Hi<br>";
    $postvars = isset($_POST)? $_POST : array("no post");
    /* echo "</pre>Post Vars:<br><pre>";
    print_r($postvars);
    echo "</pre>Refurl:<br><pre>";
    Check for the transaction ID and put it in the pament_notice table if possible. 
    */
    if (isset($postvars['item_number']) &&  $postvars['item_number'] > 0 && isset($postvars['txn_id'])){

        /* make sure that payment_number is empty on this row. */ 
        log_message('info',"PayPal transaction received.");

        if ($this->pament_notice_model->make_sure_payment_number_is_empty($postvars['item_number'])){   
            //writes the message to the local log file in CI
            log_message('debug',"PayPal payment number is empty.");

            /* set the txn_id in the slot */
            $data = array('payment_number' => $postvars['txn_id']);
            $this->db->where('entry_id',$postvars['item_number']);
            $this->db->update('pament_notice',$data);
            log_message('debug',"payment number updated. item:".$postvars['item_number']);
            log_message('debug',"payment actual cost. payment_gross:".$postvars['payment_gross']);

        }  else {
            log_message('error',"PayPal transaction attempted on non-empty payment number.");
            if (isset($postvars['item_number']))
                log_message('error',"failed request item_number :".$postvars['item_number']);
            if (isset($postvars['txn_id']))
                log_message('error',"failed request txn_id:". $postvars['txn_id']); 
        }   

    } else {
        log_message('info',"PayPal payment transaction sent with invalid data.");
        if (!isset($postvars['item_number']))
            log_message('error',"item_number is not set");

        if (isset($postvars['item_number']))
            log_message('error',"failed request item_number :".$postvars['item_number']);

        if (!isset($postvars['txn_id']))
            log_message('error',"txn_id is not set\n");

        if (isset($postvars['txn_id']))
            log_message('error',"failed request txn_id:". $postvars['txn_id']); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes...see the receiver_email variable that was passed back.

Guide here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

See Pages 42-43

Comment: Thanks so if i understand correctly i can setup IPN in my paypal settings and add a URL page and then user the $payer_email variable?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of way of handling this.

The easiest method is to collect that data prior to sending the user to paypal.
Store it in the users current session, and have paypal redirect the user back to your page automatically.

The second is to set up the Payment Data Transfer option.  I haven't fully implemented this but there is Documentation on paypal's developer site.  It basically sends a token back to your site when the user makes payment and you have to perform another HTTP post to retrieve the user data.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid them having to fill a form in until after they have signed up unusual i know but makes sense in this scenario.

I have not heard of Payment Data Transfer but thanks for the tip I will look into this.